# Probability/Counting: Drawing 2 cards in the last 4...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was thinking about a problem:

Say you have a deck of $60$ UNIQUE cards, and want to draw a particular $2$ cards in the last $4$.

Would you solve this with the following method: first you have $58!$ arrangements of the irrelevant cards, then plunk in the $2$ desired cards: $A$ and $B$ in the last $4$ spots (this gives us ${4\choose2} =6$ ways), then multiply the ways of $A;B$ which is $2!
^{AB}$  (for example)

Our probability space has $60!$ arrangements.

So we that gives us $\operatorname{P}(A;B|  \text{in the last 4 cards})=\frac{2!\times{4\choose2}\times58!}{60!}$   ?

Some follow-up clarifications: 1) Whether the cards are in the first or last set, or the middle, it doesnt matter, since position is relative and accounted for in the counting method.
2) the general formula would then be for $N$ cards, finding $x$ in a desired position of $y$ cards
$\operatorname{P}(\text{event})=\frac{x!\times{y\choose x}\times(N-x)!}{N!}$

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: What does it mean to draw the two cards "in the last $4$"?

Comment: I meant: After you go through the deck by drawing, what is the chance that 2 specific ones will be in the remaining 4 cards. I could've worded it better definitely.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your formula is correct. You can derive and write it more succinctly by noting that there are $\binom yx$ ways to choose spots for the $x$ cards among the $y$ spots and $\binom Nx$ to choose them among all $N$ cards. It seems that you're regarding all arrangements as equiprobable; then the probability is the quotient of the two, $\binom yx\big/\binom Nx$, which corresponds to your formula.

Comment: Great thanks for the post!